# ¿Cómo deshabilitar los eventos de un textarea?

Tags: javascript

Quiero deshabilitar los eventos de input text cuando la variable `cont` sea igual o mayor a 5

lo quiero usar para lo siguiente: estoy haciendo un proyecto que mediante la escritura de los usuarios se va obteniendo caracteristicas, y tengo que almacenar en la BD la misma cantidad de caracteristicas para cada usuario.

```js
var cont = 0;
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var texto = document.getElementById('captureInput');
  cont++;

  texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
    if(cont<5){
      alert("hola");
    }else{

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id='captureInput'></input>
```

Comment: Ya lo tienes hecho con un `if-else` que comprueba si `cont` es menor que 3. ¿Cuál es el problema?¿Cómo no funciona?

Comment: ¿Qué significa en este caso "deshabilitar los eventos"?

Comment: @Mariano es sobre el trabajo de Biometria de teclado, quiero para que cuando termine de escribir el texto predeterminado ya no admitir mas valores de las variables, quiero que todos los usuarios envien la misma cantidad de valores

Comment: ¿La idea seria hacer el `input` [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo quiero usar para lo siguiente: estoy haciendo un proyecto que mediante la escritura de los usuarios se va obteniendo caracteristicas, y tengo que almacenar en la BD la misma cantidad de caracteristicas para cada usuario.

Comment: No entiendo... porque no limitas desde un principio el input?? `<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">`

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo por que cuando el usuario siga escribiendo aunque ya no se escriba en el input se va almacenando por js, mi proyecto almacena los tiempos de escritura del usuario.

Comment: Ok, ya te entiendo, la solución de @sakulino no es lo que necesitas?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que el contador nunca aumenta... Deberías tener algo así:

```js
var cont = 0;
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var texto = document.getElementById('captureInput');

  texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
    if(cont<3){
      alert("hola");
    }else{

    }
    cont++;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id='captureInput'></input>
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: he actulizado mi pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que el campo de texto se limite a 3 caracteres, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var texto = document.getElementById('captureInput');

  texto.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var largo = this.value.length;
    if(largo > 3) {
      this.value = input.substring(0, largo - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="captureInput" placeholder="ingrese 3 valores"></input>
```

Lo que hace es que dentro del evento 'input' (Es el evento recomendado para este tipo de casos) se evalúa el contenido de la caja de texto. Si el largo del texto llega a ser mayor a 3, se elimina el último caracter de la derecha usando [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring).